# In Postgres, how to match multiple "tags" for best performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

Table: articles

```
+--------+------+------------+
| id     | title|    created |
+--------+------+------------+
|    201 | AAA  | 1482561011 |
|    202 | BBB  | 1482561099 |
|    203 | CCC  | 1482562188 |
+--------+------+------------+
```

Table: taggings

```
+-----------+------+
| articleid | tagid|
+-----------+------+
|    201    | 11   |
|    201    | 12   |
|    202    | 11   |
|    202    | 13   |
|    202    | 14   |
+-----------+------+
```

Now if given **3 tag ids**, what is the best index design and query to select latest 10 articles that **each article match the 3 tag ids at the same time**?
I know there can be several ways to do it, but I'm concerning the **performance**, considering there maybe tens of thousands of articles in each tag

Comment: `query to select latest 10 articles` - please explain how do you define `latest article` ? Is there a date column in some table, which is not shown in the question ? Or does `the latest` mean the highest values in `id` columns?

Comment: @krokodilko I added a column "created" to the table. And yes latest is highest value in id column. The id is "int serial".

Comment: This might be interesting for you: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html

Answer (score 22):

As [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) mentioned, this blog post has some really interesting performance benchmarks for finding rows matching more than one tag:

http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html

Storing tags in an array column in the main table and creating a GIN-index allows rows to be selected like this, without any joins:

```
select id
from articles
where tags @> array[11,13,14]
order by created desc
limit 10;
```

The column and index can be created like this:

```
alter table articles add column tags text[] not null default '{}';
create index tags_index on articles using gin (tags);
```

According to the blog, finding rows matching two tags was between 8 and 895 times faster when using the array-column than when joining in a tags table.

Comment: Has it changed since 2015?

Comment: Would be better to see a new test with the latest version of PG. is there any citation on that?

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct on (a.id) a.*
from articles a 
  join taggings t on t.articleid = a.id
group by a.id 
having array_agg(t.tagid order by t.tagid) = array[11,13,14]
order by a.id, a.created
limit 10;
```

An index on `taggings (articleid, tagid)` will help for this.

Note that the above looks for articles with **exactly** those three tags. If you want to find those with *at least* those three tags (and possibly more) you can change the having clause to use the "contains" operator:

```
select distinct on (a.id) a.*
from articles a 
  join taggings t on t.articleid = a.id
where t.tagid in (11,13,14)
group by a.id 
having array_agg(t.tagid) @> array[11,13,14]
order by a.id, a.created
limit 10;
```

In that case the `order by` for `array_agg()` is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

You need have an index on `articles.created` for sorting, and another unique index on `taggings(articleid, tagid)` for querying:

```
CREATE INDEX ON articles(created);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON taggings(articleid, tagid);
```

Then just make a select query with three `taggings` table aliases:

```
SELECT a.* FROM articles a, taggings t1, taggings t2, taggings t3
    WHERE a.id=t1.articleid AND a.id=t2.articleid AND a.id=t3.articleid
    AND t1.tagid=111 AND t2.tagid=222 AND t3.tagid=333
    ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to apply a complex condition to every "tag", and `@>` was of no use. So I found another approach: a *grid sensor* array:

```
ARRAY[
  bool_or(true if tag1 is present), 
  bool_or(true if tag2 is present),
  ...
] = ARRAY[true, true, ...]
```

Example:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM articles a JOIN tags t ON(t.articleid = a.id)
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING 
  ARRAY[
    bool_or(t.tagid == 11),
    bool_or(t.tagid == 13),
    bool_or(t.tagid == 14)
  ] == ARRAY[true, true, true]
```

it has poor performance, but great flexibility for many2many relationships.